# Does not conform to protocol AFURLResponseSerialization

Tags: swift, alamofire

Im kinda stuck in a problem with Alamofire & AlamofireImage. 
The main idea is to make a custom `imageResponseSerializer`, becouse my pics are coded in base64, so i need to uncode it first, so can't use default `imageResponseSerializer`. To do this i read manual and find that i could use a [custom-response-serializer](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#creating-a-custom-response-serializer) , so i just tried a provided example with XML serialization (pasted it to my class).
Then im trying to provide it as an `imageResponseSerializer` like this way:

```
 func configureCellWithURLString(URLString: String, placeholderImage: UIImage) {
    let size = imageView.frame.size        

    imageView.imageResponseSerializer = Request.XMLResponseSerializer()
    imageView.af_setImageWithURL(
        NSURL(string: URLString)!,
        placeholderImage: placeholderImage,
        filter: AspectScaledToFillSizeWithRoundedCornersFilter(size: size, radius: 20.0),
        imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.2)
    )
}
```

But getting the error on this line:
 `imageView.imageResponseSerializer = Request.XMLResponseSerializer()`

```
Value of type ResponseSerializer<ONOXMLDocument, NSError> does not conform to AFURLResponseSerialization in assignment
```

And now can't figure out why it is not conform or i just doing it wrong ?

Comment: I saw this gist from Reddit the other day: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b87d3e7908cfa5e02ec6 , it is an example response serializer for Ono's Swift counterpart Fuzi